# Button action not working on button on a view

Tags: ios, uibutton, uilabel

In a view I am using a label as host from a button. The label is added to `self.view`. Both objects are shown as expected, but the action defined in the button is not fired.
Here is the code:

```
datelabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];
datelabel.frame = CGRectMake(10, 200, 300, 40);
datelabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
datelabel.textColor = [UIColor blueColor];
datelabel.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Verdana" size: 18.0];

NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
df.dateStyle = NSDateFormatterMediumStyle;
datelabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",
[df stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]];

CGRect buttonFrame = CGRectMake( 170, 8, 130, 25 );
UIButton *button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame: buttonFrame];     
[button setTitle: @"My Button" forState: UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(salvarFecha:) forControlEvents:
    UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[button setTitleColor: [UIColor redColor] forState: UIControlStateNormal];

[datelabel addSubview:button];

[self.view addSubview:datelabel];
```

And here the button action code:

```
- (void)salvarFecha: (id) sender{
    NSLog(@"BOTON PULSADO");
}
```

Any help is welcome...

Comment: I have never heard of anyone adding a UIButton as a subview of UILabel. Why not add it to `self.view` as you are doing with `datelabel`?

Comment: It is a label to show the selected date from a datepicker. I wanted to  use it to put there the button to close the datepicker.

Comment: You are right, if I put the button on self.view it works....Would you please put your comment into an answer to accept it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have never heard of anyone adding a UIButton as a subview of UILabel. Why not add it to self.view as you are doing with datelabel?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you need to set `userInteractionEnabled` to `YES`

From `UIView.h`:

`if set to NO, user events (touch, keys) are ignored and removed from the event queue.`

In `UILabel.h` this field is `NO` by default

Hope this will help you